# Is it necessary to install a window manager with alongside an installation of Cinnamon on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, cinnamon

I have installed Arch Linux and realized that background images are not saved through a reboot. I did a bit of research and found a package named `feh` that apparently does this, and more, for window managers without this capability.

I further read that window managers are typically integrated into desktop environments, so I should have oen installed. The desktop environment that I installed was `cinnamon`. Therefore, I am here to ask if I am simply missing a configuration step or does cinnamon not come with an integrated window manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any desktop environment has a window manager almost by definition. Cinnamon's is called "Muffin", a fork of GNOME's Mutter, and isn't used directly but as a library loaded by the "Cinnamon shell" (`/usr/bin/cinnamon`), following the architecture of Mutter and GNOME Shell.

However, restoring the wallpaper isn't strictly a function of the window manager, it's just where *some* implementations do it.

Most standalone WMs do not have any setting for that, but they have a "startup script" which runs a tool like `feh` or `hsetroot` or even `xsetroot` (among other things that the user wants to run on startup).

Desktop environments, on the other hand, have a *settings panel* (e.g. `gnome-control-center` or `cinnamon-settings`) and a *settings store* (dconf+GSettings in case of both GNOME and Cinnamon, a directory full of .ini files in case of KDE) where the settings panel stores the chosen wallpaper, and where the window manager reads it from.

```
(high-level GSettings API)
# gsettings list-recursively org.cinnamon.desktop.background
# gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri

(low-level dconf storage)
# dconf dump /org/cinnamon/desktop/background/
```

In GNOME, this is actually read not by the window manager, but by `gnome-settings-daemon` (the central configuration manager thing that does all sorts of things).

In Cinnamon...I have no idea? Originally this was also handled by `cinnamon-settings-daemon`. Then, in version 2.0.6, suddenly [it was removed](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon-settings-daemon/commit/184bd05572d638818e74779b9752c58fa655f2cf). It seems that the functionality *was* [moved into the `cinnamon` shell](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/commits/master/js/ui/backgroundManager.js).